# What are the specific ways to use publication list

Tags: marketing-cloud, publicationlist

I understand that why we are using publication list but i am not able to understand can we add manually subscriber into publication list ?

I want to link my data extension to the publication list how can we do this ?

My data extension is used in journey builder and i want to select publication list for that.

Please assist!!

Answer (score 1):

You really should use start using [official Marketing Cloud documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_welcome.htm&type=5) before asking about basics.

You cannot link a Data Extension to a Publication List by default, this is something you at the Send level to the Data Extension used for sending.

You can only add members to Publication List *manually* if you do it either via API, SSJS, AMPscript or Automation Studio Import Activity, there is no click based option.

To use Publication List in a Journey, configure it on the Email activity Manage Contact step:

[image]

- Here's a an article how to use [Publication Lists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5).